# esliint error no console error and form hooks error

Tags: reactjs

I want to fix es lint errors. Can anybody help me fix that.

esliint error no console error and form hooks error

```
 110:3   error  Duplicate key 'padding'                         no-dupe-keys
  116:10  error  'formValid' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars
  135:9   error  Unexpected console statement                    no-console
  140:9   error  Unexpected console statement                    no-console
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { srConfig } from '@config';
import emailjs from '@emailjs/browser';
import sr from '@utils/sr';
import { usePrefersReducedMotion, useAOS} from '@hooks';
import toast,{Toaster} from 'react-hot-toast';

const StyledContactSection = styled.section`
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  text-align: center;
  
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
  }
 


  .overline {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: var(--green);
    font-family: var(--font-mono);
    font-size: var(--fz-md);
    font-weight: 400;

    &:before {
      bottom: 0;
      font-size: var(--fz-sm);
    }

    &:after {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .title {
    font-size: clamp(40px, 5vw, 60px);
  }

  .email-link {
    ${({ theme }) => theme.mixins.bigButton};
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
`;

const colors = {
  darkNavy: '#020c1b', /*background*/
  navy: '#0a192f', /* container background*/
  lightNavy: '#112240',
  lightestNavy: '#233554',
  white: '#ccd6f6'
};

const Input = styled.input`
  width: 100%;
  
  padding: 1rem;
  border: var(--lightNavy);
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  background-color: var(--light-navy);
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 16px;
  &:-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: var(--white); // Change to your desired placeholder color
  }
  &:placeholder {
    color: var(--white); // Change to your desired placeholder color
  }
  &:focus {
    outline: none; // Remove the default focus outline if you want
    color: var(--white);
   
  }
  &:-webkit-autofill {
    /* Avoid changing background color on autofill */
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:  var(--white);
    color: var(--white);
  }

  /* Reset autofill background to default */
  &:-webkit-autofill::first-line {
    background-color: var(--light-navy);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #333;
  }
  
`;




const contactFormStyles = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  gap: '1rem',
  maxWidth: '20rem',
  margin: '0 auto',
  marginTop: '50px',

  '@media (minWidth: 768px)': {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    gap: '0.5rem',
    maxWidth: 'auto',
  },
};
const textareaStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '7rem',
  padding: '0.5rem',
  borderRadius: '0.375rem',
  backgroundColor: colors.lightNavy,
  border: colors.lightNavy,
  color: colors.white,
  fontSize: '16px',
  padding:'15px'
};

const Contact = () => {
  const prefersReducedMotion = usePrefersReducedMotion();
  const form = useRef();
  const [formValid, setFormValid] = useState(true);
  

  const sendEmail = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

     // Check if any field is empty
   const name = form.current.from_name.value;
   const email = form.current.from_email.value;
   const message = form.current.message.value;

    if (!name || !email || !message) {
      // Show a popup or error message here
      toast.error('Fill in all the fields.');
      setFormValid(false); // Set form as invalid
      return;
    }

    emailjs.sendForm('portfolio_email', 'reply_mail', form.current, 'al37jb6Jn3lJeHRUw')
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result.text);
      toast.success(' Email sent successfully!');
      setFormValid(true); // Reset form validation status
  }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.text);
  });
};
  const revealContainer = useRef(null);
  useAOS();

   useEffect(() => {
    if (prefersReducedMotion) {
      return;
    }

    sr.reveal(revealContainer.current, srConfig());
  }, []);


  return (
    <StyledContactSection id="contact" ref={revealContainer}>
    <h2 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay='50' className="numbered-heading overline">What’s Next?</h2>

    <h2 data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay='100'  className="title">Get In Touch</h2>

    <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay='150'>
      I'm <b><u>currently looking for any new opportunities</u></b>, my inbox is always open.
      Whether you have a question or just want to say hi, I’ll try my best to get back to you!
    </p>

    <Toaster 
    position="top-center"
    reverseOrder={false}
    gutter={8}
    containerClassName=""
    containerStyle={{}}
    toastOptions={{
      // Define default options
      className: '',
      duration: 5000,
      style: {
        background: 'var(--light-navy)',
        color: '#fff',
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'row'
      },
  
      // Default options for specific types
      success: {
        duration: 3000,
        theme: {
          primary: 'green',
          secondary: 'black',
        },
      },
    }}
  />enter image description here
      <form data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay='200' ref={form} onSubmit={sendEmail} style={contactFormStyles}>
        <Input
          placeholder="Name"
          type="text" name='from_name'
        />
        <Input
          placeholder="Email"
          type="email" name='from_email'
        />
        <textarea
          placeholder="Message"
          style={textareaStyles} name="message"
        />
        <button className="email-link" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
     
     </StyledContactSection>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

I want to add notification on form submit on my react application. I have used react-hot-toast and added custom code for validations. Can anybody help me fix such that it can be deployed successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s fix one by one:

- `110:3   error  Duplicate key 'padding'`

  In `textareaStyles` you have 2 **padding**, please remove one.
- `116:10  error  'formValid' is assigned a value but never used`

  If check the third line in **Contact** component you will see that you have a state called **formValid** and you are not using it. You can do the following on the submit button to fix it:

  `<button className="email-link" type="submit" disabled={!formValid}> Submit </button>`
- The other 2 errors can be fixed by removing the 2 `console.log` in **sendEmail** function.